# Help with rigging

Tags: rigging, objects

When I rotate or move my rig, it does this weird thing where it looks all weird. I have already made the object merged by distance. Does anyone know how to fix this or make it look more natural?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Thanks alot, but now for some reason I can see the edges I made in object mode and in edit mode they are kinda weird...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show some images in edit mode

Comment: @SHikhaMittal I'm not sure if that's clear enough but...

Comment: unless you have reasons to keep tris, maybe you should try to transform your tris into quads? In Edit mode select all and ctrl F > Tris to Quads, then give your object a Subdivision Surface modifier?

Comment: @moonboots changed them to quads and even tried to subdivide but still same problem :|

Comment: try Sculpting or remesh or decimate in the modifiers

Comment: please share your file (keep only the important part): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=9jdpx2P0" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/9jdpx2P0/)

Comment: try to keep quads instead of tris, give your object a Subdivision Surface modifier, correct the weight in Weight Paint mode and it will work fine

Comment: @moonboots how do I weight paint it so that there will be none of this?

Comment: your problem is essentially a problem of topology and you need to give it a Subdivision Surface, but the weight is bad too so you need to give it a correction

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep quads instead of tris (you can even simplify your topology with some edge dissolve), give your object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, correct the weight in *Weight Paint* mode and it will work fine:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

When you work your topology, if you have enabled the *Subdivision Surface* modifier, deactivate the 2 last display options:

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot, but now for some reason I can see the edges I made in object mode and in edit mode they are kinda weird...

Comment: I've edited my answer, it's because of the Subdivision Surface modifier